# std::tr1 with visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, tr1

I have some C++ code that uses some version of Google's GTest framework. This code used to compile fine with Visual Studio 2015. I just upgraded to VS2017, and now I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
error C2039: 'tr1': is not a member of 'std'
error C3083: 'tr1': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
```

Is some compiler option needed to use std::tr1 in VS2017?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option is to re-enable TR1; do this by defining the macro `_HAS_TR1_NAMESPACE`, as briefly mentioned in [this blog article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-3/). If you're using an MSBuild project then this is best done by way of your project's [Preprocessor Definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions) setting; or if you're using a precompiled header, by defining it at the top of said PCH.

A better option is to inform GTest that your compiler supports C++11 by defining the macro `GTEST_LANG_CXX11` to `1` before including any GTest headers; then it will use `std::tuple` rather than `std::tr1::tuple`*. ([GTest's C++11-detection logic](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/a2b8a8e07628e5fd60644b6dd99c1b5e7d7f1f47/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h#L321) is `__cplusplus`-oriented, which VC++ has not yet updated despite being mostly C++11 and C++14 compliant. I would say this is a bug in GTest since it supports VC++ elsewhere throughout the configuration logic.)

* Not to mention the other C++11 features, which is why this is by far the better option ;-]

Comment: Thanks. I opted for _HAS_TR1_NAMESPACE option and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Googletest [release 1.8.1](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.8.1) fixes this issue (in combination with VS2017 15.8.5).